# Paste button disabed in 18.04 Ubuntu Gnome Desktop VNC

Tags: 18.04, gnome, vnc

I am using Ubuntu 18.04 and my GNOME VNC version is 3.28.4. I have my `vncconfig`running, and when I copy some text and try *right-click* → *Paste*, *Paste* is disabled. This never works. Here is a screenshot of the issue:

[image: Screenshot of Paste Button Not Working]

Is there a patch that I can try in order to fix this?

There are no errors found in the VNC log as well. Below is my `xstartup` file.

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

[ -x /etc/vnc/xstartup ] && exec /etc/vnc/xstartup

export XKL_XMODMAP_DISABLE=1
export XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP="GNOME-Flashback:GNOME"
export XDG_MENU_PREFIX="gnome-flashback-"
source /etc/profile
gnome-session --session=gnome-flashback-metacity --disable-acceleration-check --debug &
vncconfig -iconic &
```